# ProGuard obfuscation removes parameter

Tags: java, proguard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you stop Proguard from removing type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924425/how-do-you-stop-proguard-from-removing-type-parameters)

I'm trying to obfuscate my code and I'm having no success at all...

I'd like to know if is there any way to obfuscate a desktop application which uses Spring MVC?

But now, the problem:
I have a class with this List:

```
    //bi-directional many-to-many association to PerfilAcesso
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="FuncionalidadesLiberadas", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Funcionalidades")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PerfilAcesso")})
private List<PerfilAcesso> perfilAcessos;
```

And when I obfuscate with ProGuard, it removes the parameter <PerfilAcesso>..

Comment: I don't know a solution but I would suggest looking into the -keep option in the proguard definition

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann is right... that's what I was looking for. Sorry.. And that solved my problem