# Field.getGenericType() returns instance of java.lang.Class instead of Type

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection, proguard

I'm having issues with proguard and some reflection stuff.

**Myclass.java**

```
package not.obfuscated
class MyClass {
    public List<InnerClass> childs;
}
```

**InnerClass.java**

```
package not.obfuscated
class InnerClass {
    //.somestuff
}
```

Inside proguard.cfg I have:

```
-keep class not.obfuscated.** {*;}
```

Inside another class I manage to get the "Field" instance for the MyClass.childs field and then try to get the getGenericType to determine which class is inside the List brackets (< InnerClass >)

For logging purposes I did the following Log.d code (*field* is the instance of Field representing MyClass.childs):

```
Log.d("FIELD", field.getName()+" generic type: "+ field.getGenericType()+ " class: "+ field.getGenericType().getClass().getName());
```

The output is following (2nd line):

[image: LogCat output]

As you see the field.getGenericType.toString() may be correct, but when I ask for the class it returns java.lang.Class. Indeed, a couple of line afterwards, when I do:

```
ParameterizedType listType = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
```

I receive a ClassCastException:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

I strongly believe this is due to proguard, but as far as I know of proguard I already excluded all the classes inside the not.obfuscated package. As last try I also inserted the line -keep class java.lang.List (obviously nothing happened).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default Proguard removes some of the type information: [How do you stop Proguard from removing type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924425/how-do-you-stop-proguard-from-removing-type-parameters)

Adding the following line should fix the issue:

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

May be the whole magic line would work, i.e.:

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: -keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature

Comment: Hello, i've added at the top of my proguard but it does not work
-keepattributes Signature

I must mention i do have another -keepattributes *Attributes* before that.

Comment: Hey, may be it cuts off the information about inner classes - I've updated with a full line - hope it will help.

Comment: Hey @Andrey, gradle was not recompiling the source using the new proguard file. The solution (first line you proposed) works perfectly :) Thanks

Comment: Fixed my retrofit and rxjava project. Cheers