# Missing type parameter. Proguard?

Tags: android, android-proguard

Since I updated my Android Studio, I get at certain parts of my App this exception:
"Missing type parameter."

I found on Stack Overflow this answer:
[How do you stop Proguard from removing type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924425/how-do-you-stop-proguard-from-removing-type-parameters)
or this 
[proguard Missing type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129040/proguard-missing-type-parameter)

But even after adding the suggested lines

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes  Signature,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
```

in my proguard-android.txt I still get the error. I dont even know why, for most people it seemed to fail with classes which use Gson, but most of my classes using Gson work fine.

I also dont even know where I specified to use Proguard, in my Module Gradle file nothing is specified, just some libraries have it in there gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this issue but I finally figured out why I was getting it. In the build.gradle file I never included `proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'` in the buildTypes -> debug. So this is what mine looks like:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```