# Android proguard not working

Tags: java, android

Proguard rule which I am using is below and com.example.gym.pojo is package name

`-keep class com.example.gym.pojo.** { public *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.example.gym.pojo.** { public *; }`

```
My class `import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BulkUserResponse {

    public String message;
    public boolean success;
public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> customers;
public ArrayList<FeesInfo> fees;}`
```

After Proguard rule applied class look like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;public class BulkUserResponse {
public ArrayList customers;
public ArrayList fees;
public String message;
public boolean success;}
```

I want the same pojo class as it is after applying proguard. because I want to parse all the pojo class. I am using GSON library.

After applying proguard I want  my class with `public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> customers`

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: You want to obfuscate class and ArrayList of customers?

Comment: `public ArrayList customers;` - it has public ArrayList customers after proguard, can't you see?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Comment: I want public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> customers; after progaurd apply

Comment: there is no way, and it is even not a ProGuard's fault. After compilation collections have no type, they are just `ArrayList` without the element type. This is how the Java works.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use different approach. GSON library supports serializing and deserializing with annotations. 
You can do something like this:

```
public class BulkUserResponse {
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    public String message;
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    public boolean success;
    @SerializedName("customers")
    @Expose
    public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> customers;
    @SerializedName("fees")
    @Expose        
    public ArrayList<FeesInfo> fees;
}`
```

This way event if field name will be obfuscated, GSON will still serialize fields with your names.

And for saving your Generic types (`ArrayList<FeesInfo>` for example), use this `-keepattributes Signature`. [Link to original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924425/how-do-you-stop-proguard-from-removing-type-parameters)

Comment: I am able to parse the data, but when I am trying to read members of customer class am not able to do, bcz after progaurd it difficult to to understand the which type of arraylist. My problem will get resolved if I get public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> customers after progaurd applied

Comment: I have added only '-keepattributes Signature'  and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have added

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

And after progaurd applied my class look like, and that was I am expecting

```
public class BulkUserResponse {
public ArrayList<CustomerInfo> customers;
public ArrayList<FeesInfo> fees;
public String message;
public boolean success;}
```

Thanks Ekalips...

Comment: It's my pleasure. You can mark my answer as an solution then.